# How do I handle null values in a generic var comparison?

Tags: c#, generics, equality

I have a method retrieving a value from a dictionary by key, or returning a default value if not found

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue existingValue))
    {
        return existingValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

When used in a generic method, the default value is set to `default(T)` because it can be a value or reference type

```
T myGenericVar = myDict.GetValueOrDefault(key, default(T));
```

Now I want to compare this var in order to understand if the value is found in the dictionary, but the operator `==` cannot be used since the compiler doesn't know if it's a value or reference type. So I used `Equals`

```
bool found = myGenericVar.Equals(default(T))
```

It happens that if `T` is a reference type, `default(T)` is actually `null` and calling `Equals` on null produces a `NullReferenceException`

How can I avoid the exception?

Comment: In that specific case, `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(myGenericVar, default(T))` is best. You *can* use `Equals(myGenericVar, default(T))`, but that will box value types.

Comment: But, there's a reason that `Dictionary.TryGetValue` follows the pattern where it returns `bool`. It's a lot easier to test a `bool` to see whether the value was found in the dictionary, than to test whether the value you got back is the same as some default

Comment: "Now I want to compare this var in order to understand if the value is found in the dictionary" that's pointless. If you have a `0`, does that mean `0` was stored in the dictionary, or does it mean you got `default(int)`? There is a reason the `TryGet` does what it does. Don't hide it an then guess it's result later. Just use it directly.

Comment: @canton7 actually this is an example, but it can happen also in different scenarios

Comment: I edit the question because the point is not the dictionary, it is equality

Comment: @Phate01: just pass the information if it was contained to the caller method, either as return value or as out parameter. That's much better than comparing the value with the default value.

Comment: Please dont completely change the question to a different question. Ask a new one

Comment: It's really difficult to deal with this generically because the defaults of structs vs reference types are quite different beasts. For instance, an `int` value of `0` is quite a common one, will tend to have meaning in a lot of domains and can be used in exactly the same way as any other `int`. Whereas any default reference type is null and doesn't represent something "usable".

Answer (score 2):

As hinted in the comments, if you want to know whether the default is returned or not create another method `TryGetValueOrDefault`:

```
public static bool TryGetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue defaultValue, out TValue value)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out TValue existingValue))
    {
        value = existingValue
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        value = defaultValue;
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution, but my question was more about the behaviour of the language and less about the specific case. I upvoted